# Generate vector in $\mathbb{Z}^3$ with fixed sum and uniform distribution

Tags: simulation, random-generation, uniform-distribution

I need to generate 3 discrete random variables whose sum is equal to a specified value (fixed) and is uniformly distributed, however each component of the sum has specified bounds.  For example,
$$
X_1 + X_2 + X_3 = S
$$
where $a_1 \leq X_1 \leq b_1$, $a_2 \leq X_2 \leq b_2$, and $a_3 \leq X_3 \leq b_3$.

I found this [Random Vectors with Fixed Sum](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9700-random-vectors-with-fixed-sum), but it only allows a single bound to be given that then applies to all the $X$s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it more general!

1. Generate a random $X_1$ value between $a_1$ and $b_1$;
2. Generate a random $X_2$ value between $a_2$ and $b_2$;
3. Compute $X_3$ as $S - X_1 - X_2$ and check whether the generated number belongs to the interval $a_3$ and $b_3$. If the value belongs to the interval return the three generated values, restart from step *1.* otherwise

You can extend the algorithm to a generic $R^n$ space